# How to return multiples names from 2 vectors

Tags: r

I've created a vector for age,

`age <- c(18, 21, 22, 17, 19, 19, 20)`

and also a vector for names.

`name <- c("Emily", "John", "Michael", "Alex", "Olivia", "Sophia", "Noah")`

The names correspond to the ages. I am supposed to find the people who are older than 18. I know how to return for who has the youngest age through

`name[which.min(age)]`

which returns Alex, but I'm stuck on how to get everyone who is older than 18 (which should be everyone except for Alex). Thanks!

Comment: Try `name[age >= 18]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
name[age > 18]
```

or

```
subset(name,age>18)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the vectors in a dataframe and subset the dataframe on your condition:

```
df <- data.frame(age, name)
df$name[df$age >= 18]
[1] Emily   John    Michael Olivia  Sophia  Noah   
Levels: Alex Emily John Michael Noah Olivia Sophia
```